# How to resolve ambiguity in my GADTs

Tags: haskell, types, dsl, gadt

I have two GADTs I am using to model a SQL EDSL. To keep the client facing api clean and simple I want to use `OverloadedStrings` to cast string literals to a `Column Selection`.

Therefore you can simply type

```
select ["a", "b"] $ from tbl
```

instead of

```
select [Column "a", Column "b"] $ from tbl
```

The problem is that select allows for both `Column Selection`s and `Reduction`s
to allow for queries that perform aggregations.

```
mean :: Column Selection -> Column Reduction

select :: [Column a] -> Query b -> Query Selection
select [mean "a"] $ from tbl
```

and thus the strings are ambiguous in this context of `[Column a]`.
But `select [mean "a"] $ from tbl` is valid since `mean` provides the necessary context to infer that the string literal is a Column Selection.

Can anyone recommend a way out of this mess?

**My current code below (irrelevant instances omitted)**

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    GADTs
  , RankNTypes
  , DataKinds
  , TypeFamilies
  , FlexibleContexts
  , FlexibleInstances
  , OverloadedStrings #-}

data Sz = Selection | Reduction deriving Show
data Schema = Schema{name :: Maybe String, spec :: [Column Selection]} 

type family ColOp (a :: Sz) (b :: Sz) where
    ColOp Selection Selection = Selection
    ColOp Selection Reduction = Selection
    ColOp Reduction Selection = Selection
    ColOp Reduction Reduction = Reduction

data Column (a :: Sz) where
    Column  :: String -> Column Selection
    Assign  :: String -> Column a -> Column a
    FKey    :: String -> Schema -> Column Selection
    BinExpr :: BinOp  -> Column a -> Column b -> Column (ColOp a b)
    LogExpr :: LogOp  -> Column a -> Column b -> Column Selection
    AggExpr :: AggOp  -> Column Selection -> Column Reduction

instance IsString (Column Selection) where
    fromString s = Column s

data Query (a :: Sz) where
    Table  :: Schema -> Query Selection
    Select :: [Column a] -> Query b -> Query Selection
    Update :: [Column a] -> Query b -> Query Selection
    Where  :: [Column Selection] -> Query Selection -> Query Selection
    Group  :: [Column Selection] -> Query Selection -> Query Reduction
```

I would also like to make the following signature fail for `Select`/`Update`:

```
[Column Selection] -> Query Reduction -> Query Selection
```

But that's a whole other can of worms...

Comment: `mean "a"` typechecks just fine with this code, and the inferred type of the `"a"` is precisely `Column 'Selection`. Then the type of `Select [mean "a"]` is `Query b -> Query 'Selection`. If something doesn't work, please include precisely which expression causes the ambiguity and what the actual error is. You have not defined `from` or `tbl` anywhere, so perhaps the error is related to those functions.

Comment: right but `select ["a"] $ from tbl` does *not* typecheck.

Comment: `from = Table` and `tbl = Schema {name= Just "tbl", spec= [Column "a", Column "b"]}`

Comment: Perhaps: `select :: [Column Selection] -> Query b -> Query Selection; reduce :: [Column Reduction] -> Query b -> Query Selection; select = Select; reduce = Select`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is correct to give you an ambiguous type error for `Select ["a"]` - the `IsString (Column Selection)` instance can be chosen *only* if *a priori* the argument to `Column` is known to be `Selection`. This is exactly the intended behaviour.

What you want is the following:

```
instance (x ~ Selection) => IsString (Column x) where
    fromString = Column
```

This will allow the compiler to infer that `"x" :: Column _` must actually be `"x" :: Column Selection`, as opposed to *requiring* it.

`Select [mean "a"]` is a completely different situation - since `mean :: Column Selection -> Column Reduction`, the compiler knows, before instance selection happens, that `"a" :: Column Selection`, because the type of `mean` forces this to be the case.